# Creating a public Member organisations directory with CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: civimember, civireport

i'm new to CiviCRM but i've been trying to Create a public Member organisations directory with CiviCRM in Wordpress.

i've tried to configure a public report of members but it appears empty when i'm not logged in see here...
http://phils07813188309.esy.es/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F37&reset=1

I don't know if this is a permissions issue, something to do with privacy settings or that i'm approaching the problem from entirely the wrong angle

And advice or pointers would be appreciated...

Ta

phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for this is to create a profile (**Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles**).  Check out [this page](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/) in the section labeled "Displaying information on public pages", and also "Making directories with Profiles", further down that same page.

Comment: Great thanks for that - wouldn't have found it on my own!

Comment: Ok i've posted a follow up question here...    [link](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/creating-a-public-members-directory-with-civicrm-in-wordpress-using-profiles)