# Creating a public Members directory with CiviCRM in Wordpress using Profiles

Tags: civimember, profile, permissions, smartgroups

I'm trying to create a public Members directory with CiviCRM in Wordpress using Profiles.

First i created a "Smart Group" through Search that lists all the members filtered as i wanted - i've called this Smart group "Members Directory (Smart Group)" and set it's Visibility as "Public Pages".

Then i created a Profile called "Members Directory (profile)" and populated it with a few "Individual" fields like First & last name: each set with Visibility as "Public Pages and Listings", Searchable "YES", In Selector? "Yes". I linked this to my smart group.

Finally i put the CiviCRM shortcode [civicrm component="profile" gid="14" mode="view"] on my page.

However when i view my page it says...

```
(i) Permission Denied You do not have permission to view this contact record. Contact the site administrator if you need assistance.
```

See here...
http://phils07813188309.esy.es/membership/members-directory-from-profile/

Any ideas what is going on?
phil

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  Having same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are seeing this as an anonymous visitor to the site and it fuctions properly if you are logged in.  If this is the case, I think you'll need to add anonymous users as able to see the information for these public profiles.  In CiviCRM go to Administer > User and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control). Select the 'Wordpress Access Control'.

You can provide anonymous users (all visitors to the website who have not logged in) permissions such as:

- create and edit profiles ( or profile listings and forms)

This is typically on by default, so someone might have turned it off.

See the Book for more details:

http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Alternatively, if you cannot see the page properly as an authenticated user, or if this permission is given, something else may be amiss.

For a starting point, here are some unresolved forum posts with the same issues:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,34677.15.html

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=30429.0

This could be a bigger bug that needs reported/fixed

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks. I checked those access permissions and "CiviCRM: profile listings" and "CiviCRM: profile listings and forms" were both off for all users so i switched them on.

Comment: HOWEVER the problem remains - for an anonymous user the error is "_Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Could not find the required contact id parameter (id=) for viewing a contact record with a Profile._" and for the authenticated admin user it says "_Permission Denied You do not have permission to view this contact record. Contact the site administrator if you need assistance._".  Strangely the "**>>Back to Listing**" link provided then takes me to the correct members directory profile listing.

Comment: Yep - the link http://phils07813188309.esy.es/membership/members-directory-from-profile/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&force=1&gid=14 seems to work for authenticated and anonymous users - so it is the CiviCRM shortcode that is not working properly.

Comment: Which is eactly the problem this guys was having in 2013 with no solution... http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=30429.0

Answer (score 3):

I'm on WordPress with CiviCRM 4.6.3 and was experiencing a similar issue viewing a page with the profile search shortcode as a Subscriber role. However, it was throwing a different permissions error:

> The requested Profile (gid=43) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR >you do not have permission to access this profile.

WordPress Access Control menu in CiviCRM for that particular role had everything in order (profile listings, profile listings and forms) as well.

The issue turned out to be in that particular Profile's Settings. In the "Used For" field, only the "Search View" option was checked. I needed "Standalone Form or Directory" checked as well. I suspect this is because embedding the form with that shortcode is not considered a "CiviCRM Basic and Advanced Search" as the documentation calls it. It's a form that can display search results.

Hopefully this works in your case as well.

Cheers,

Jonathan