# Shortcode and permissions for WordPress publicly searchable member directory

Tags: wordpress, civimember, search

This is a fairly broad question: a client wants to have a publicly searchable member directory. So I'm looking at some old questions, such as [Creating a public Members directory with CiviCRM in Wordpress using Profiles](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/creating-a-public-members-directory-with-civicrm-in-wordpress-using-profiles) and [Creating a public Members directory with CiviCRM in Wordpress using Profiles and shortcode](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/creating-a-public-members-directory-with-civicrm-in-wordpress-using-profiles-and) with no luck.

Is there a shortcode for a publicly (not as member and not logged in) searchable member directory? *(I have told the client this has privacy implications.)*

This is currently being used but returns no results:

`[civicrm component="profile" gid="11" mode="search" hijack="0"]`

[image]

But not showing search results may be a result of no permissions for the anonymous user, as I read in one of the linked questions. I've given anonymous users the capabilities for profile listings and forms and profile listings in Administer >  WordPress Access Control. I've set up a Smart Group and a profile, outlined on https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/ . But that doesn't help.

Using:
WP 5.2.4
CiviCRM 5.17.5

Comment: Does it return results for a logged in user?

Comment: No results for logged in users.

Answer (score 2):

This problem turned out to be a Javascript error in the console:

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' on civicrm:1`

A plugin must have been dumping in Javascript in the header or footer, and once it was deactivated, CiviCRM could render the search results in Javascript.